# Image sizes when uploading to Tumblr. Pages showing different rules than for Posts. How to lazyload Post images

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I am working with a pretty customised Tumblr account. I have a mixture of pages and posts where I want to access content and assets (mainly images to use in other posts and/or pages).

When I upload a file to a page, the default image size is 500px as per part of the image url. However as I know all the images I am uploading are large I have written a basic lazy load function to fetch the 1280px version of the file once it is in the view port.

For example:

500px: https://64.media.tumblr.com/e833cfdd76698ce60459a05e4501cf3d/tumblr_inline_s8e723yQER1r2a01g_500.jpg

1280px https://64.media.tumblr.com/e833cfdd76698ce60459a05e4501cf3d/tumblr_inline_s8e723yQER1r2a01g_1280.jpg

That code looks like this:

```
const setImageSource = () => {
    images = document.querySelectorAll('#posts img');
    images.forEach(item => {
        const newSrc = item.src.replace('500', '1280');
        item.setAttribute('data-src', newSrc);
    });
    observeImages();
};
```

This works and I have no issue with it.

However when I add images to a post they are being output with a default large url. For example:
https://64.media.tumblr.com/8bb2edad047e9fbe8fcd2484064ddcfb/c16d798313ac9970-1e/s2048x3072/a422c651ec6c093d3a5ae0634bc84f91e7793b24.jpg

I don't recognise this format, and wonder if it was introduced as part of the NPF (or some other development).

My question, are there smaller versions of the images uploaded to Tumblr that I can access.
How do I derive the file url.The only thing I can see in the new url format that might help is `/s2048x3072/`

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe we can access different versions of the images uploaded in a post! I also think it's how an NPF—Neue Post Format—post is rendered (referring to your question regarding the URL output).

Here is the comparison from the same image:

**Legacy, taken from [demo](https://demo.tumblr.com/post/459265350/passing-through-times-square-by-mareen-fischinger):**

- https://64.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_kzjlfiTnfe1qz4rgho1_1280.jpg

**NPF, taken from [my test blog](https://fukuo-test.tumblr.com/post/741662460777529344/passing-through-times-square-by-mareen-fischinger)**

- https://64.media.tumblr.com/53cd28e33afb4a3cbf8a2cf3f8af37a0/d173aaf637281c7c-17/s1280x1920/90a09059bd2c07e935cc88fe114849f6f4319cef.jpg

---

When inspecting the image element on the blog network (e.g https://yourblog.tumblr.com/) in an NPF post, additional image sizes should be visible by default in the `img` tag. These sizes are indicated by the `srcset` attribute, which contains various image sources.

(This assumes you're using the base code provided by Tumblr, where the NPF image is generated from the `{Body}` variable to display content)

[image]

Here is a simple script to print out various image sizes via console:

```
const imgElements = document.querySelectorAll('.tmblr-full img');

if (imgElements.length > 0) {
    imgElements.forEach(imgElement => {
        const srcset = imgElement.getAttribute('srcset');
        const srcsetArray = srcset.split(',').map(item => item.trim());
        
        const imageUrls = srcsetArray.map(item => {
            const [url, width] = item.split(' ');
            return { url, width: parseInt(width, 10) };
        });
        
        console.log(imageUrls);
    });
}
```

[image]

#### From the screenshot above, the smaller versions of the images should be:

- s75x75
- s100x200
- s250x400

Replacing your current URL with another version from `s2048x3072` to `s250x400` should be working:

https://64.media.tumblr.com/8bb2edad047e9fbe8fcd2484064ddcfb/c16d798313ac9970-1e/s250x400/a422c651ec6c093d3a5ae0634bc84f91e7793b24.jpg

I hope this helps!

Comment: awesome thank you. The fact that NPF is spitting out the various optimised sizes means I might not actually need to implement lazy load for the images. But thank you so much for suppling the code to inspect the various sizes. I assumed perhaps they might not work as the hashed url part (after the `s2048x3072`) but it does seem to work. Thanks again!

Comment: I also thought it might not work because of the different hashed URLs it served, but weirdly enough, it still works if we only change the size versions  well, at least I think it's working (for now)